# Release version works from Visual studio not from explorer

Tags: debugging, release, explorer

I have an application querying a server displaying some images. It works fine when I ran it from Visual studio release mode or Debug mode.

But when i run it from windows  Explorer it has trouble loading those images, takes for ever.  Debug exe from Explorer works. Any suggestions on how to debug this is greatly appreciated. Adding message boxes again might change the behavior.

Shashi

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

1. Consider logging relevant information to a text file and then comparing the files between running inside the debugger vs. outside.
2. Start up the application in Explorer, then in Visual Studio do `Debug -> Attach to Process` in the menu and attach the debugger to your process.
3. If your application is connecting to the server over http, download an application like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine the messages being sent.

Comment: Thanks Erik. All are good tips. It was doing the same thing when I attached the process as well. However I found out the issue. Sometimes when i ran from the explorer, some variables which were controlling couple of loops were getting some huge values,and the loops go for ever, because of improper data transfer from server. Seemed like a timing issue.